# Preparing Dataset for a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) model to classify hand gestures. Dataset is not readily available and hence I need to prepare it.

How should i prepare the dataset? Should the images I capture contain objects other than the hand or only the hand? Which will give me an accurate model that will work accurately despite of background and other objects in the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Dataset for your problem:

> You should consider involving different backgrounds and objects in background.

Following links might help you:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

https://www.quora.com/Computer-Vision-What-is-the-best-way-to-collect-Train-and-Test-data-images-for-object-recognition-job

Answer (score 1):

here is an example:
http://cims.nyu.edu/~tompson/NYU_Hand_Pose_Dataset.htm

it containing other images would just mean you have to implement something in your pipeline to isolate the hand. i would recommend having only the hand in the images so you can just start modelling on the images right away.

a lot of cnn architectures in this area using multi-resolution CNNs. so in your data preparation just make multiple resolutions and feed to a multi input CNN. you can make this using Keras functional API. low res images are fine for differentiating between certain very different poses and the higher res can focus on small differences.

obviously, standard data augmentation is not that suitable for hand pose. stuff like mirroring or changing the angle could make your data unsuitable for the given label. so be a bit more conservative with your data augmentation if you don't have that much.